# Center span elements with float attribute

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I have *span* elements that i want to be floated and centered. **I need the span floated so they don't disappear when screen width is less than the spans width. If floated they will jump to next line one by one as screen shrinks**. I think i can center using 3 floated `divs` but i was wondering if there is a simple way of doing this and without setting fixed width on anything.

Applying `display:inline-block` to the spans won't work. `text-align: center` is inherited.

## HTML

```
<div style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div style="float:left;">
       <span style="float:left">FOO</span><span style="float:left">BAR</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: A JSFiddle explaining it: https://jsfiddle.net/5yyhdpf1/

Comment: I just want the floated spans to stay side by side in the center, in one line. Because when screen width is lower than their width, the "float" will make the span go to next line as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Span elements are inline by default, adding `text-align: center` to parent is all you need, why do you complicate it? What is the point of floats?

```html
<div style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <span>FOO</span><span>BAR</span>
</div>
```

There is no such thing as center floating, instead you have to use `margin: auto` to center block-level elements.

Comment: The floated spans will align vertically (go to next line) when width is smaller than the span width. See EDIT in question

Comment: I found the solution, the behavior i want don't come from "float" but from "inline-block". It wasn't working exactly due to "float". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The *inline-block* attribute set to all span elements without any floats will behave that way. The "*text-align: center*" must be set on the parent div.

```
<div style="text-align: center">
  <span style="display: inline-block">FOO</span><span style="display: inline-block">BAR</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,
  try this,

```
 <!--html-part-->
 <div style="float:left">
    <span style="float:left">FLOATEDSPAN</span>
    <span style="float:left">FLOATEDSPAN</span>
    <span style="float:left">FLOATEDSPAN</span>
    <span style="float:left"></span>
    <span style="float:left">FLOATEDSPAN</span>
    <span style="float:left">FLOATEDSPAN</span>
    <span style="float:left">FLOATEDSPAN</span>
    <span style="float:left">FLOATEDSPAN</span>
    <span style="float:left">FLOATEDSPAN</span>
    <span style="float:left"></span>
    <span style="float:left">FLOATEDSPAN</span>
    <span style="float:left">FLOATEDSPAN</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <span>NONFLOATED</span>
  <span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span><span>NONFLOATED</span>
```

/*css-part*/
span{width:300px; text-align:center; float:left;}